# Confused about the definition of $ \limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n$

Tags: calculus, limits

This may be a stupid question, but isn't $\displaystyle \sup a_n$ simply a fixed number rather than a sequence? 
Doesn't it remain constant as n varies?

In that case what does:

$\displaystyle \limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n$

mean?

Answer (score 1):

You are somehow right. The following definition may be more understandable:

$$\limsup_{n\to \infty}(a_n)=\lim_{m\to \infty}(\sup_{n\geq m}(a_n))$$

Answer (score 0):

"$lim sup a_n$" does NOT mean "the limit of the supremum of the sequence $\{a_n\}$.  That is, it is not "$lim (sup a_n)$ but rather $(lim sup) a_n$.  "lim sup" is a separate operator in its own right- it means "the supremum of the set of all subsequential limits of $\{a_n\}$.

If a sequence **converges** to a single limit, then the set of all "subsequential limits" contains only that single value and so both $lim sup a_n$ and $lim inf a_n$ are the same- the limit of the original sequence.

But if a sequence does **not** converge it has no limit but may has "lim sup" and "lim inf" (any **bounded** sequence has both).  For example, the sequence ${(-1)^n} does not converge but all subsequences that have only odd or only even powers of -1 do.  The set of subsequential limits is {-1, 1}.  The larger is 1 so that is the "lim sup" and the smaller is -1 so that is the "lim inf".